# Dart Flutter: Why does the terminal outputs these lines?

Tags: class, flutter, dart, output

New to dart, go easy on me.

I am starting to work on APIs and a part of my training is to fetch data from a [World Time API](http://worldtimeapi.org/).
I created a separate class that fetches the data and imported it in the get time page in order to initialize it in `initState`.
Here is my class:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';


class WorldTimeClass {
  String flag; // this is the link to a .png flag
  String url; // this is the suffix of the location e.g.: Europe/Berlin
  String time; // this is the time format to be displayed to the user
  String location; // this is the location, say Berlin

  WorldTimeClass({this.flag, this.url, this.time, this.location}); // class object

  Future<String> getData() async { // async method to fetch the data
    Response load = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url');
    Map x(){if(load.statusCode == 200){ // if all goes well, fetch content from API
      print(load.statusCode); // this is so I can see that the operation is successful

    Map map = jsonDecode(load.body); // converting String to MAP
    return map;} // returning Map Object
    else{ // in case of error
      print('No Access');
      return {1:'NoAccess.'};} // had to return a Map Object since I declared Future<Map>
   }

    String datetime = x()['utc_datetime']; // fetching datetime String
    String offsetUTC = x()['utc_offset']; // fetching offset, e.g. +01:00
    DateTime dateTimeObjectConvert = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    // Below converts the datetime string to a DateTime Object and then converts the UTC Offset to a substring only '01' out of +01:00 and then converts it to an int Object and then adds it to the DateTime Object as a Duration (hours);
    dateTimeObjectConvert = dateTimeObjectConvert.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offsetUTC.substring(1,3))));
    return time = dateTimeObjectConvert.toString(); // returning String to be displayed to user

  }

}
```

And here is my code inside the app page `choose_location.dart`:

```
Future<String> provisionalFunc() async {
    String getdata;
    WorldTimeClass instance = WorldTimeClass(location: 'Algiers', url: 'Africa/Algiers', flag: 'algeria.png');
    getdata = await instance.getData();
    return getdata;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState..');
    super.initState();
    print(provisionalFunc());
  }
```

Problem: In the terminal output I get this:

```
Restarted application in 1 174ms.
I/flutter (24151): initState..
I/flutter (24151): Instance of 'Future<String>'
I/flutter (24151): 200
I/flutter (24151): 200
```

Questions:

1. Why do I get code: 200 twice ?
2. Why do I get `Instance of 'Future<String>'` and how to get rid of it?
3. How to print the time String variable in my terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I get Instance of 'Future' and how to get rid of it?

> How to print the time String variable in my terminal?

Try this way to get your time value from `'Future<String>'`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    provisionalFunc().then((timeData) =>
    {
      print(timeData);
    });
    
  }
```

> Why do I get code: 200 twice ?

Your status code is printing twice because some of the reason your `Map x() {}` is called twice if you print log outside this it will print only once

> Try this way to get your time

Create a pojo class to parse your json

```
class TimeData {
  String abbreviation;
  String client_ip;
  String datetime;
  int day_of_week;
  int day_of_year;
  bool dst;
  int dst_offset;
  int raw_offset;
  String timezone;
  int unixtime;
  String utc_datetime;
  String utc_offset;
  int week_number;

  TimeData(
      {this.abbreviation,
      this.client_ip,
      this.datetime,
      this.day_of_week,
      this.day_of_year,
      this.dst,
      this.dst_offset,
      this.raw_offset,
      this.timezone,
      this.unixtime,
      this.utc_datetime,
      this.utc_offset,
      this.week_number});

  factory TimeData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TimeData(
      abbreviation: json['abbreviation'],
      client_ip: json['client_ip'],
      datetime: json['datetime'],
      day_of_week: json['day_of_week'],
      day_of_year: json['day_of_year'],
      dst: json['dst'],
      dst_offset: json['dst_offset'],
      raw_offset: json['raw_offset'],
      timezone: json['timezone'],
      unixtime: json['unixtime'],
      utc_datetime: json['utc_datetime'],
      utc_offset: json['utc_offset'],
      week_number: json['week_number'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['abbreviation'] = this.abbreviation;
    data['client_ip'] = this.client_ip;
    data['datetime'] = this.datetime;
    data['day_of_week'] = this.day_of_week;
    data['day_of_year'] = this.day_of_year;
    data['dst'] = this.dst;
    data['dst_offset'] = this.dst_offset;
    data['raw_offset'] = this.raw_offset;
    data['timezone'] = this.timezone;
    data['unixtime'] = this.unixtime;
    data['utc_datetime'] = this.utc_datetime;
    data['utc_offset'] = this.utc_offset;
    data['week_number'] = this.week_number;

    return data;
  }
}
```

> now update your `getData()` method like this

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    // async method to fetch the data
    Response load = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url');
    print(load.statusCode);

    if (load.statusCode == 200) {
      var timeDate = TimeData.fromJson(json.decode(load.body));
      String datetime = timeDate.utc_datetime; // fetching datetime String
      String offsetUTC = timeDate.utc_offset; // fetching offset, e.g. +01:00
      DateTime dateTimeObjectConvert = DateTime.parse(datetime);
      // Below converts the datetime string to a DateTime Object and then converts the UTC Offset to a substring only '01' out of +01:00 and then converts it to an int Object and then adds it to the DateTime Object as a Duration (hours);
      dateTimeObjectConvert =
          dateTimeObjectConvert.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offsetUTC.substring(1, 3))));
      return time = dateTimeObjectConvert.toString();
    }else{
      return "No access";
    }

    // returning String to be displayed to user
  }
```

Now use like this

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState..');
    super.initState();
    provisionalFunc().then((timeData) => {print(timeData)});
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: because of `String datetime = x()['utc_datetime']; // fetching datetime String
    String offsetUTC = x()['utc_offset']; `

Comment: `x()` is called twice

Comment: @dev-aentgs Thank you, is there a way to call it once but fetch the two keys? 
I.e., ```utc_datetime``` and ```utc_offset```.

Comment: yes, you already have the result, save it in `Map variable` and access. like `Map results = x(); String datetime = results['utc_datetime'];String offsetUTC = results['utc_offset'];`

Comment: One call is fetching all the data, just need to save and access it @MehdiRezzagHebla